# Swift: doesNotContain method for Array

Tags: ios, swift

I am familiar with the `contains(array, object)` function, but I am in need of a "does not contain" function. I can't think of any logic to work around it, so I could use some help!

My code currently is the exact opposite of what I need. It is only appending objects that are contained in the `array`; I want it to append every object that is NOT in `array`.

Code is here:

```
var array = ["Ben", "Jessica", "Cody", "Katie", "Jacob"]
if array.contains("Ben") {
    print("Contains Ben")
}
```

Comment: `if !contains (...) { ... }`???

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I forgot to try that.

Comment: you got 3 upvotes for that :O

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Feeling dumb.

```
!contains(array, "Ben")
```

Answer (score 13):

The ".contains(element)" command returns a Bool, meaning these 2 statements produce the same result

```
if array.contains("Ben") { code }
if array.contains("Ben") == true { code }
```

Therefore

```
if array.contains("Ben") == false { code }
```

Will execute code if the array does not contain the value

Answer (score 5):

while the other answers show some errors while compiling here a working solution for `doesNotContain`

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func doesNotContain(_ element: Element) -> Bool {
        return !contains(element)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This seems like a very sensible convenience operator which makes the code much easier to read. The only suggestion I would make, is maybe it should be `extension Collection` instead of `extension Array`?

Answer (score 1):

You could also write an extension on Array

```
extension Array {
    func doesNotContain <T: Equatable> (items: T...) -> Bool {
        return !contains(items)
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like `yourArray.doesNotContain(item1, item2, item 3)`.

Comment: it is not really a fortunate choice to deal with negative statements, like _"does-not-contain?"_... well, _"no, it does not"_ or _"yes, it does not"_...? it is better to just simply avoid such confusion, and using positive statements only.

Comment: This does not work because the Array Element has no relationship with T. It would throw an error `Cannot convert value of type '[T]' to expected argument type 'Element'`

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Returns **true**, if the array does not contain all of the presented items

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    
    func containsNoOne(of array: [Element]) -> Bool {
        for item in self {
            if array.contains(item) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    
}
```